# Solving the equation $x^{ (\frac{x}{123}+11)} =123$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I came across this equation

$$x^{ \left(\frac{x}{123} + 11 \right) } = 123 $$

All I could think of is to put $ \ln $ into the equation:

$$
\begin{align}
\ln\left(x^{ \left( \frac{x}{123} + 11 \right) } \right) &= \ln\left(123 \right) \\
\ln(x)\cdot \left(\dfrac{x}{123}+11\right) &= \ln\left(123 \right)
\end{align}
$$

and I'm lost.

What should I do now?

Comment: This doesn't look solvable, but it appears that $x \in (1,2)$

Comment: @RustynYazdanpour Sorry I wrote the wrong title... It is supposed to be $x^{x/123+11}=123$

Comment: WolframAlpha says $x \approx 1.548$. Are you supposed to approximate it?

Comment: @MichaelBiro Yeah. And mainly I want to know what algorithm should be applied to question of this type

Comment: You were lost before that.  Taking $\ln$ of both sides you should get $\left(\frac{x}{123}+11\right) \ln x = \ln 123$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MichaelBiro states above in the comments, wolframalpha, gives an approximate solution over the reals: 
$$
x\approx 1.54801
$$
Using this value of $x$ gives a relative error of:
$$
\approx -.001 \text{%} 
$$
You can try Newton's method, since you know your root $x^* \in (1,2)$

The newton iteration is as follows:
$$
x_0 = 1.5 \\
$$
$$
x_{n+1} = x_n-\frac{(123 x_n^{\left(\tfrac{-x_n}{123}-10\right)})(x_n^{\left(\tfrac{x_n}{123}+11\right)}-123)}{(x (\ln(x)+1)+1353)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You won't find a closed-form solution.  Try Newton's method.